# Search in set of sets

Tags: python, set, frozenset

I would like to search in a set of sets in a specific way:

Example (Pseudocode):

```
search = {{1}, {3}}
search_base = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
# search results in True
```

because the 1 can be found in the first set and the 3 in the second.
Order doesn't matter, but the number of subsets has to be identical, the search consists always of singletons.

Example (Intuition):

```
search = {{"Vitamin D"}, {"Sodium"}}
search_base = {{"Vitamin D", "Vitamin"}, {"Sodium", "NA"}}
```

I want to know if search (a combination of two materials with different hierachical names) is in the search base. The search base here only contains a single entry.

---

What I tried:

*Using frozensets instead if sets for the hash.*

```
search = frozenset([frozenset([1]), frozenset([3])])
search_base = frozenset([frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([3, 4])])

all_matched = []
for i, set_ in enumerate(search):
    for bset_ in search_base:
        if not set_.isdisjoint(bset_):
            all_matched.append(True)
print(len(all_matched) == len(search))
```

It feels very clunky and therefore my question is if there is a much smarter (better performance) way to solve this.

Comment: What is being searched, and for what? search and search_base don't really explain it for me.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk added an example. basically I want to know if for the search set there is another set in the search_base which shares an element for each subset.

Comment: Are the sets in `search` always singletons?

Comment: @j1-lee added an intuitive example and another comment. For your eamples, #1 would result False, #2 would result true

Comment: @blhsing yes, always singletons

Comment: So you should mention that about the #2 example from @j1-lee instead of saying it would return `True`.

Comment: @blhsing True, added it to the question.

Comment: @j1-lee the datatype isn't important, the frozensets are the result of me trying to solve the problem, not a specification, I thought they make the most sense.

Comment: Can the sets in `search_base` overlap? What should be the result if `search = {{1}, {3}}` and `search_base = {{1, 2}, {1, 4}}`? With your implementation it returns `True`, but is it correct?

Comment: @blhsing result should be False, because if you look at my "inutitive" example it would mean that 1=Vitamin D occures 2x where the 3=Natrium is missing in the search_base.

Comment: Exactly, which is why I brought it up because it means your current implementation does not exactly work as intended and cannot be used as a reference solution.

Comment: @blhsing, ahhh you are right. My bad. I haven't consider that yet, thanks for the hint!

Comment: And what if the items in `search` do not cover every set in `search_base`, but are all *covered* by at least one set in `search_base`? For example, your implementation would return `True` for `search = {{1}, {2}}` and `search_base = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`, but is it correct?

Comment: @blhsing in this case it would also be False, Intuitivly spoken: the sodium would be missing.

Comment: Aside from the needless use of `enumerate`, this doesn't seem clunky at all (other than the clunky state of affairs that arises from having a bunch of singleton sets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the data type is not important, I will just use a list of numbers and a list of sets. You can nest `all` and `any`, with `in` to check set membership:

```py
def search(nums, sets):
    return all(any(x in y for y in sets) for x in nums)

print(search([1, 3], [{1, 2}, {3, 4}])) # True
print(search([1, 2], [{1, 2}, {3, 4}])) # True
print(search([1, 5], [{1, 2}, {3, 4}])) # False
print(search(["Vitamin D", "Sodium"], [{"Vitamin D", "Vitamin"}, {"Sodium", "NA"}])) # True
```

As for performance, this does not improve upon your current code. I doubt there are any (performance-wise) better ways unless there are more restrictions on the input data.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, I found another solution, where we use the cartesian product to create a tuple of ground truth and check if the search set is in there:

```
search = {1, 3}
search_base = ({1, 2}, {3, 4})

from itertools import product
new_search_base = tuple(set(x) for x in product(*search_base))
print(search in new_search_base)
```

Comment: The creation of `new_search_base` has a time complexity of *O(2 ^ n)*, which can get very costly quickly if/when *n* gets large.

Comment: @blhsing that is true, however for my usecase it is fine. Thats also the reason I accepted the other answer of j1-lee and not this one, but I wanted to add it in case future readers have a similar use case as I.